# Detecting headers status takes too long

Tags: php, performance, http

I have a table in my database with 35000 unique URLs. I use them to create my XML sitemaps for the site. I have setup crontab jobs to create automatically new URLs, delete non existing URLs and determine if a URL is valid.

For the last part I use the following function:

```
function get_url_status($url)
{
    $httpCode = 0;
    $headers = get_headers($url);
    $http_header_info = $headers[0];
    $httpCode = substr($http_header_info, 9, 3);

    if ($httpCode=='200')
    {
        // check in page for noindex and dissable that url
        $metas = get_meta_tags($url);
        if ( isset($metas['robots']) && strpos( strtolower($metas['robots']),  'noindex')!==false  )
        {
            $httpCode = 410;
        }
    }

return $httpCode;
}
```

This will return to me the HTTP status code - 200 for legal URLs that will be included in sitemap, 400 for not found, 410 for URLs with noindex in them, 301 for redirections, etc.

In my XML sitemaps I include only URLs with status code 200.

My problem is that this function takes around 40 minutes to check the URLs in database. Is there a way to speed things up?

Comment: What part takes 40 minutes?  If you're fetching all the records from the database I wouldn't be surprised about that runtime (you do have an index for the URL I hope).

Comment: @ferada - yes db table has indexes, this function is used in a loop where each url from db is checkeck. So, what other way is there?

Answer (score 1):

So you're fetching 70k pages.  You could half that if you only fetch the page once and then do what `get_headers` and `get_meta_tags` do manually.  That will presumably take now 20 minutes.

Then you can try doing this in parallel, so run two instances of the script with one half of the URLs each.